# hiddenText = ca.a.getText(); gives NullPointerException?

Tags: java

Edit: Thank you for all the answers, really helped a lot and some nice tips.

Hi everyone,
            I'm new here and new to Java programming so i will try to provide any relevant information as best i can.

My problem is i am trying to create two classes, the first class (ClassA) is a GUI, the second (ClassB) is the logic for (ClassA).

A simple example of my code is:-

**ClassA**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ClassA extends JFrame {


JTextField a = new JTextField();

JButton but = new JButton("Click");

ClassB cb = new ClassB();


public ClassA() {
    setTitle("Test");
    setLookAndFeel();
    setSize(250, 100);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GridLayout mainGrid = new GridLayout(1, 1, 20, 20);
    setLayout(mainGrid);


    add(a);
    add(but);
    but.addActionListener(cb);
    setVisible(true);
}


private void setLookAndFeel() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel"
                );
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        //ignore error
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassA Alch = new ClassA();
}

}
```

**ClassB**

```
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ClassB implements ActionListener{
String command;
String text;

ClassA ca;



@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    command = event.getActionCommand();
    if (command.equals("Click")) {
        text = ca.a.getText();
        System.out.println(text);
    }

}
}
```

The problem i am having is getting ClassB to read JTextField *a*.

If i remove the line

```
text = ca.a.getText();
```

and use

```
System.out.println(command);
```

it outputs Click so the rest of the code seems to work but as soon as i add

```
text = ca.a.getText();
```

i get a NullPointerException when i use the "Click" button.

So the question is how should i be writing the code to get ClassB to read the JTextField and therefore output it?

Answer (score 1):

You have `ClassA` variable `ca` but you haven't initialised it yet. So First you need to initialise the `ca` variable in order to use it.

```
ClassA ca - new ClassA();
```

---

Not relevent to your question, but as you said you are new to java so. Always remember never ever have an instance variable of your interface class inside your logic class. Its a bad design.

I recommend you to find some good articles about MVC design pattern and then jump back into OOP. It is always better to create strong foundation :)

Answer (score 1):

The `ca` variable was never initialized. You need to add something like `ClassA ca = new ClassA()` somewhere in your `ClassB` -- probably in a constructor.

**Clarification edit**

Per comment:

If the variable gets initialized within the constructor, it will need to use `ca = new ClassA()`, otherwise the variable will be scoped only within the constructor. So, for example:

```
public ClassB() {
    ca = new ClassA();
}
```

However, if you do not wish to add the constructor for whatever reason, you could also modify the variable's existing declaration:

```
public class ClassB implements ActionListener{
    String command;
    String text;
    ClassA ca = new ClassA();
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you do `ClassA ca = new ClassA()` in a constructor for ClassB you're going to create a variable scoped to the constructor that shadows the `ca` **field** in that class.

Comment: That's what the word *like* indicates. Obviously if it's in the constructor, it should be `ca = new ClassA()`, whereas the OP could otherwise just modify the declaration of the variable where it is to be `ClassA ca = new ClassA();`. But since the OP does claim to be new to the language, I will update my post to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create an instance of ClassA in ClassB :

```
ClassA ca = new ClassA();
```

then you should know that ca is an instance variable and if you dont initialize an instance variable it get null value.

tip: it is better to make your instance variable private and access to them by getter and setter method:

```
private JTextField txtField1 = new JTextField();

private JButton btnAction1 = new JButton("Click");

private ClassB cb = new ClassB();

public JTextField getTxtField1() {
    return txtField1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize the field `ca` of ClassB in the constructor of ClassA by calling `cb.ca = this`, but that is kind of dirty. Fields should almost always be private, i. e. not accessible from outside the class.

Best way to solve this is to forget ClassB and use anonymous class instead of it. In the constructor of ClassA add new anonymous implementation of ActionListener.

```
but.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        command = event.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals("Click")) {
            String text = a.getText();
            System.out.println(text);
        }
});
```

Alternatively, you can provide the label as an argument to constructor of ClassB and save it to a field (of ClassB).

```
private JTextField field;

public ClassB(JTextField field) {
    this.field = field;
}
```